# Display dynamically generated forms next to each other in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I generate dynamic forms based on a json file. But they will be displayed among each other like this:

[image: Displayed false]

but it should be displayed like this (this is for example 3 inputs, if I have 4 the fourth one should be next to the third one and so on.. )

[image: Displayed right]

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in json" :key="index">
  <b-form-input v-if="item.type" :type="item.type"></b-form-input>
</div>
```

my object:

```
[
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "label": "Input Type Text",
        "type": "text",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "label": "Input Type Number",
        "type": "number",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "key3",
        "label": "Input Type Number",
        "type": "number",
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

I've tried to solve it with `class="row"`, but its not working because it's still the same that they are among each other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible that it should only "col-6" my input fields. I have also some selectoin and checkboxes... these I want to have "col-12"

Two ways I would approach this, depending on circumstances

First, if you can edit your input object and want more freedom in your classes you could do this:

**Method 1**

Edit your object to include classes

```
[
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "label": "Input Type Text",
        "type": "text",
        "value": "",
        "classes": "col-6"
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "label": "Input Type Number",
        "type": "number",
        "value": "",
        "classes": "col-6"
    },
    {
        "key": "key3",
        "label": "Input Type Number",
        "type": "number",
        "value": "",
        "classes": "col-6 another-class"
    }
]
```

Then use the classes in your  html

```
<div class="row">
  <div
    v-for="(item, index) in json"
    :key="index"
    :class="item.classes"
   >
    <b-form-input v-if="item.type" :type="item.type"></b-form-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2**

Assign classes with a condition based on input type

```
<div class="row">
  <div
    v-for="(item, index) in json"
    :key="index"
    :class="{
      'col-6': item.type === 'number' || item.type === 'text' || item.type === 'email',
      'col-12': item.type === 'select' || item.type === 'checkbox',
    }"
   >
    <b-form-input v-if="item.type" :type="item.type"></b-form-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

answer based on [s4k1b's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12281663/s4k1b)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Just for information is it possible to write this code lines for ":class" in my methods?

Answer (score 2):

From the tags I can see you are using bootstrap

In bootstrap you can use `row` and `col` to align items side by side in a row.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in json" :key="index" class="col-6">
    <b-form-input v-if="item.type" :type="item.type"></b-form-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you ! That works out well - but is it possible that it should only "col-6" my input fields. I have also some selectoin and checkboxes... these I want to have "col-12"